# unable to find utility <>, not a developer tool or in PATH

Tags: r, rstudio

I am on OSX and using rstudio, and trying to install the `igraph` package using the command `install.packages("igraph")`

One of the errors that comes up when I try to do this is that R cannot find the package `make` in my path. The specific error is:

> xcodebuild -sdk '' -find make 2> /dev/null
> make: error: unable to find utility make, not a developer tool or in PATH
> checking for gcc... gcc
> checking whether the C compiler works... no
> configure: error: in
> /private/var/folders/45/d1bkzyzs1z1fyrs2x05vpfqm0000gn/T/RtmpUolWnz/R.INSTALL57656bb59fb8/igraph:
> configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
> See `config.log' for more details
> ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘igraph’

- removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/4.0/site-library/igraph’

The thing is, make is already in my path. as I can see by calling the command:
`Sys.getenv("PATH")`, `/usr/bin` is in my PATH, which contains the `make` command.

When I try to run `make` in the terminal, it is recognized no problem. However when I run the system command `make` from R, I get the same error:  `error: unable to find utility "make", not a developer tool or in PATH`

In summary: clearly, `make` is in my path, both according to the command line and Rstudio. However, for some reason Rstudio is not recognizing the command despite being in the path.

Can anyone explain why this might be happening?

Comment: Have you tried restarting RStudio? Does `Sys.which("make")` also return a path?

Comment: yes, `Sys.which("make")` returns `/usr/bin/make`

Comment: It appears that while my `/usr/local/bin/make` is functioning correctly, in the PATH, it is my `/usr/bin/make` which is getting picked up in the Rstudio environment, and which is giving the above error. I want to be able to update my `/usr/bin/make` file to symlink to the correct place, or even just delete it, but apparently the recent MacOS big sur/Catalina update I did is preventing me from doing this, even as root. :/